# word-wrap an hover is not supporting in internet explorer 5

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I am mouse over on li elements the long content of li element should be wrap. The following code is working in all the browsers except internet explorer 5. can you please help me to fix in ie5?

```css
<style type="text/css">
   #breakText{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0px !important;
   }
   #breakText li{
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 48px auto 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    <!-- text-overflow: ellipsis; -->
    display: block;
   }
   #breakText li:hover{
    white-space: normal;
    background-color: yellow;
   }
  </style>
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
  </script>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <ul id="breakText">
   <li>This li contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line. </li>
   <li> thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</li>
   
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't think [`word-wrap`](https://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap) and [`:hover`](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahover) are supported in IE 5

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you supporting IE5?

Comment: I'm not supporting IE5 :-D @idoric  , but we have to run our application in IE5  only. So

Comment: @acchu Jesus, feel sorry for you man. Why IE5 only? Sorry for the questions, but I find this interesting.

Answer (score 2):

IE 5 doesn't have the pseudo hover on elements other than the anchor tag "a".

Also the "a" tag is selected only if it has an href attribute. So you may want to try a simpler case where the hover is detected. Instead of changing text wrapping, let's do text color for now:

```
<style>
li:hover{color:red;} /* won't work */
a:hover{color:red;} /* this works */
</style>

<li>this won't change</li>
<a href=# onclick="return false;">this will change on hover</a>
```

Comment: Thank you Schien. But my question is also with word wrap. Is there any alternate way to break the long word and wrap to next line which works in ie5 ?

Comment: I wish I had access to an IE5.5 machine at the moment so I can write out answers that are tested. If there is no styling option that wraps the text in IE5, then it's a different issue. You are dealing with 2 matters - one is the selection, the other is the actual payload.